# Non-static edit() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android-studio, static, sharedpreferences

Good evening. Or whatever time you're reading this in. In Android Studio when I was developing the first stages of my app I ran into a problem and I can't seem to find the answer. I am trying to use SharedPrefereces to save user input, but when I try to edit the prefereces [editor = SharedPreferences.edit();] it says that edit() is a non-static method and connot be refereced from a static context.

Here is the code.

public class TheButton extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText ed1, ed2, ed3, ed4;

/*EditText nameInput;
EditText ageInput;
EditText occupationInput;
EditText genderInput;
Button startButtonFinish;*/
protected static final String MyPREFERENCES = "";
public static final String nameInput = "";
public static final int ageInput = 0;
public static final String occupationInput = "";
public static final String genderInput = "";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_button);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageInput);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.occupationInput);
    ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.genderInput);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Button startButtonFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButtonFinish);
    startButtonFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nL = ed1.getText().toString();
            String oI = ed3.getText().toString();
            String gI = ed4.getText().toString();

            //Gives me an error on edit() saying that it edit() is a non-static
            // class and they cannot be referenced from a static context
            editor = SharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(nameInput,nL);
            editor.putString(occupationInput, oI);
            editor.putString(genderInput, gI);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(TheButton.this, thebutton2.class));
        }
    });



}
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line editor = SharedPreferences.edit();
you should call edit method by sharedpreferences object which is initialized in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `.edit()` method by creating object of `SharedPreferences`. Change `SharedPreferences` in line, from `editor = SharedPreferences.edit();` to `editor = sharedPreferences.edit();`

```
EditText ed1, ed2, ed3, ed4;

/*EditText nameInput;
EditText ageInput;
EditText occupationInput;
EditText genderInput;
Button startButtonFinish;*/
protected static final String MyPREFERENCES = "";
public static final String nameInput = "";
public static final int ageInput = 0;
public static final String occupationInput = "";
public static final String genderInput = "";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_button);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageInput);
    ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.occupationInput);
    ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.genderInput);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Button startButtonFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButtonFinish);
    startButtonFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nL = ed1.getText().toString();
            String oI = ed3.getText().toString();
            String gI = ed4.getText().toString();

            //Gives me an error on edit() saying that it edit() is a non-static
            // class and they cannot be referenced from a static context
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(nameInput,nL);
            editor.putString(occupationInput, oI);
            editor.putString(genderInput, gI);
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(new Intent(TheButton.this, thebutton2.class));
        }
    });



}
```